# Getting deprecated error when running tests, even tho the test results are good

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rubygems

❯ rails test
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Running via Spring preloader in process 4541
Run options: --seed 56928

## Running:

/home/lcsmachado/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:355: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/home/lcsmachado/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:118: warning: The called method `[]' is defined here ./home/lcsmachado/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:355: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call /home/lcsmachado/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:118: warning: The called method` []' is defined here
........

Finished in 0.650968s, 13.8256 runs/s, 15.3617 assertions/s.
9 runs, 10 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

The test result is okay, but i don't know the cause of those errors messages, in my opinion it is on rails root files, so i prefer to not change then, but i'm actually learning rails and don't know much.

Comment: That's pretty normal with Ruby and not a big problem.  You should monitor deprecation warnings to see if they relate to your own code, because you'll want to correct it before a new version of Ruby or Rails actually removes the functionality you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecation errors in code can sometimes get annoying though it won't get in the way until there's a significant library upgrade that finally removes that deprecated logic, forcing programmers to finally do something about it if they wish to stick with the latest and greatest.

I noticed the stacktrace in question might be incomplete, which could be leaving some important hints that helps identifying not only where the root cause is, but most impotantly what in the proprietary code is calling it to begin with. Either way, it's a warning, the tests passes and as far as I can tell it'll only become a priority/urgency even, when there's a real need.

With that being said, the error seems more around the easier side of things where as it states, the number of arguments being passed down the line is different than ideal. Looking into the Gem doc and try to trace it back will probaly get closer to where the issue to be addressed is.